# Xcode Mac OS pasting columns of text

Tags: xcode, macos

In Mac OSX you can select  a block or column of text using the Option key as a modifier. But when you then paste the copied text, it inserts as if a single line. Is there any way to have it paste as columns? That is, each line in the copied block would insert in a corresponding line in the target text like cut and past of columns in a spread sheet.
I'm trying to do this in text files within Xcode but it seems a more general quetion associated with the the Mac OS.

Comment: Try BBEdit (free version TextWrangler) - it handles copy/paste of columns quite well.

Comment: Paul, thanks. I was hoping for a simple shortcut as opposed to adding more to the pipline but I'll give that a try if nothing else avails.

Comment: Yes, it depends on how much of this type of editing you need to do, but BBEdit is a great editor anyway, and it can do a lot more than Xcode's built-in editor, so it's useful to have around. It's free sibling, TextWrangler, has a lot of the same functionality, so you could start with that.

Comment: Thanks again. I actually have BBEdit around, just haven't added it after a clean install.

Comment: Yep. Not only as advertised, far more robust than editing text in Xcode. Worth adding to the work flow for columnar editing. Thanks again.

Comment: Great - glad it works for you - I know I wouldn't be without it!